# Adding nagios plugins to nconf schema

Tags: nagios

I've got nagios and nconf installed and I'm starting to add host and service definitions. What I notice though is a large discrepancy between the list of available nagios modules which can be used to add a service and those available on my nagios server.

To see which nagios plugins nconf let's you configure:

```
SELECT CV.attr_value AS nagios_plugin
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
JOIN ConfigValues CV ON CV.fk_id_attr = CA.id_attr
WHERE
CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
CA.attr_name = 'command_name';
```

which returns

```
+----------------------+
| nagios_plugin        |
+----------------------+
| check_local_disk     |
| check_local_load     |
| check_local_procs    |
| check_local_users    |
| check_local_swap     |
| check_local_mrtgtraf |
| check_ftp            |
| check_hpjd           |
| check_snmp           |
| check_http           |
| check_ssh            |
| check_dhcp           |
| check_ping           |
| check_pop            |
| check_imap           |
| check_smtp           |
| check_tcp            |
| check_udp            |
| check_nt             |
+----------------------+
```

Comparing that to what's on disk `ls -1 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins`, shows there's close to 70 nagios plugins that aren't exposed in nconf!

My question - before I contrive the SQL statement to add support for commands I'm interested in using, like `check_mysql`, is there a place where the appropriate `INSERT` statements are already available? Is there a better way to go about this? Seems like nconf only gives you a limited set of nagios plugins to use out-of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying out my own chops to add support for `check_mysql`. Since the server I want to connect to supports SSL, I built a check command in nconf specific to ssl connections called `check_mysql_ssl`. Here's the SQL I ran to get it added. I'll write up a full blog post in the near future with more detail. Note, the reason for the bulky amount of SQL is the EAV paradigm used by the nconf database ;)

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------------
-- Store some variables for future use
-- ------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT @command_name_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'command_name';

SELECT @command_line_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'command_line';

SELECT @command_syntax_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'command_syntax';

SELECT @default_params_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'default_params';

SELECT @command_param_count_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'command_param_count';

SELECT @default_service_name_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'default_service_name';

SELECT @service_template_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'service_template';

SELECT @default_service_dependency_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'default_service_dependency';

SELECT @dependency_execution_failure_criteria_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'dependency_execution_failure_criteria';

SELECT @dependency_notification_failure_criteria_attr_id := CA.id_attr, @config_class_id := CC.id_class
FROM ConfigClasses CC
JOIN ConfigAttrs CA ON CA.fk_id_class = CC.id_class
WHERE
  CC.config_class = 'checkcommand' AND
  CA.attr_name = 'dependency_notification_failure_criteria';

-- ------------------------------------------------------------
-- Create a new ConfigItem
-- ------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO ConfigItems SET fk_id_class = @config_class_id;
SET @config_item_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();


-- ------------------------------------------------------------
-- Add support for check_mysql
-- ------------------------------------------------------------

-- command name
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('check_mysql_ssl', @command_name_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- command line
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('$USER1$/check_mysql -H $ARG1$ -u $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$ -l -C $ARG4$ -a $ARG5$ -k $ARG6$', @command_line_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- command syntax
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('ARG1=host, ARG2=username, ARG3=password, ARG4=ca-cert, ARG5=client-cert, ARG6=client-key', @command_syntax_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- default params
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('!', @default_params_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- command param count
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('6', @command_param_count_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- default service name
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('', @default_service_name_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- service template
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('', @service_template_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- default service dependency
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('', @default_service_dependency_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- depdency execution failure critieria
-- @note Return non-zero - how to specify that ??
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('', @dependency_execution_failure_criteria_attr_id, @config_item_id);

-- depdency notification failure critieria
-- @note Return non-zero - how to specify that ??
INSERT INTO ConfigValues (attr_value, fk_id_attr, fk_id_item)
VALUES ('', @dependency_notification_failure_criteria_attr_id, @config_item_id);
```